# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index while inserting into table

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement

I have been working with a snippet of code where `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index` is being thrown at `runtime`.

I have worked several times in past with this exception and every time i find that developer has used wrong indexes while using `rs.getsString()` method.

But my problem this time is that i am getting this exception while inserting the records into the table. Can any one please suggest what is the reason why i am getting this exception while inserting into the database?

Also i am not able to see the query being executed at the time of exception because the driver being used (oracle drivers) don't print the query when i try to use `prepareStmt.toString()`. This method print the object reference instead.

Please help. Any help is highly appreciated.

Best Regards
Anubhav Jain!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the problem is you do setXXXX to a prepared statement with wrong index (for example 0 or bigger than the number of '?' in the SQL statement)

Comment: This also happens for PreparedStatment. Perfect explanation at http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/01/javasqlsqlexception-invalid-column.html

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. Later I found out that in my query string I had used **quote marks** around **?** symbol, which is not allowed.

For example :
 
`insert into document_table(ID, SOURCE, DESTINATION, STATUS) values('?','Active','Backup' ,'D')` 

is **not allowed.** It should have been written as:
`insert into document_table(ID, SOURCE, DESTINATION, STATUS) values(?,'Active','Backup' ,'D')`